# How Do I check if I'm holding/changing an input slider?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to validate via javascript, no jquery, if the user is currently changing an input slider. I can find nothing in slider reference.

any tips are welcome thanks

Comment: sorry I missed the no jquery part...removing my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var isSliding = false;

slider.addEventListener('input', function () {
  isSliding = true;
  output.innerHTML = isSliding;
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  isSliding = false;
  output.innerHTML = isSliding;
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9bkurra/

If I understand you correctly, you could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

As your 'slider' is an <input type="range"/> you can listen for change-events.

```
document.getElementById('mySlider').addEventListener('change', function () {...});
```

See http://devdocs.io/dom_events/change *"The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value"*